# trouble connecting to mongodb from python shell

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using python to connect to `mongodb`. At the mongodb side, I am getting the connection, bust is terminated immediately. I am new to mongodb. Kindly suggest me what can be the possible issue. through mongo shell I can ad and retrieve entries, but I cant do the same through python shell. I am running version db version v3.0.6

```
import pymongo
try:
    client = pymongo.MongoClient()
except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as e:
    print e.code
    print e.details
db = client['test']
db.main.insert({'k':10})
```

Output e.code:

```
None
```

Output e.details:

```
local 2015-10-08 01:02:05.913000
isma True
maxMessage 48000000
o 1.0
maxBsonOb 16777216
minWire 0
maxWire 3
maxWriteB 1000
```

Output at mongod side

```
2015-10-08T06:31:45.323+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.6
2015-10-08T06:31:45.323+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 1ef45a23a4c5e3480ac919b28afcba3c615488f2
2015-10-08T06:31:45.323+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-67-194-123 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-10-08T06:31:45.323+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-10-08T06:31:45.323+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-10-08T06:31:45.329+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-10-08T06:32:05.913+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55913 #1 (1 connection now open)
2015-10-08T06:32:05.914+0530 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:55913 (0 connections now open)
```

Comment: Which `pymongo` version are you using?

Comment: I am running version db version v3.0.6

Comment: No, what `pymongo` python package version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
```